# Read and Write to PhysicalDrive0 using DeviceIoControl

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, hard-drive

I have this code, that should make changes to the PhysicalDrive0, so I try to read from it, change the buffer and write it back.

Read:

```
HANDLE device = CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr);
if (device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open the drive. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY storage_query;
storage_query.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
storage_query.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;

STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER storage_descriptor;

DWORD bytes_returned = 0;
if (!DeviceIoControl(device, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &storage_query, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
                     &storage_descriptor, sizeof(STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER), &bytes_returned, nullptr)) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to query storage property. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(device);
    return 2;
}

DWORD buffer_size = storage_descriptor.Size;
BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[buffer_size];

if (!DeviceIoControl(device, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &storage_query, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
                     buffer, buffer_size, &bytes_returned, nullptr)) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to query storage property again. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(device);
    delete[] buffer;
    return 3;
}
```

Then I want to change some things on the buffer.
And then write it back:

```
if (!DeviceIoControl(device, IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_PROPERTY, buffer, buffer_size, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr)) {
    unsigned long code = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "Failed to write to the drive. Error code: " << code << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(device);
    delete[] buffer;
    return 5;
}

std::cout << "Write successful." << std::endl;

CloseHandle(device);
delete[] buffer;
```

EDIT 1: Also tried this:

```
ULONG new_buffer_size = sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET) + buffer_size;
BYTE* new_buffer = new BYTE[new_buffer_size];

STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET set;
set.SetType = PropertyStandardSet;
set.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;

memcpy(new_buffer, &set, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET));
memcpy(new_buffer + sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET), buffer, buffer_size);

// Write the buffer combined with STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET and STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR (buffer), I also tried with no output buffer, but same issue
if (!DeviceIoControl(device, IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_PROPERTY, new_buffer, new_buffer_size, new_buffer, new_buffer_size, &bytes_returned, nullptr)) {
    DWORD code = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "Failed to write to the drive. Error code: " << code << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(device);
    delete[] buffer;
    delete[] new_buffer;
    return 5;
}

std::cout << "Write successful." << std::endl;

CloseHandle(device);
delete[] buffer;
delete[] new_buffer;
```

EDIT 2: Also tried this:

```
ULONG new_buffer_size = sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET) + buffer_size;
BYTE* new_buffer = new BYTE[new_buffer_size];

STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET set;
set.SetType = PropertyStandardSet;
set.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;

memcpy(new_buffer, &set, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET));
memcpy(&((STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET*)new_buffer)->AdditionalParameters[0], buffer, buffer_size);

// Write the buffer combined with STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET and STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR (buffer), I also tried with no output buffer, but same issue
if (!DeviceIoControl(device, IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_PROPERTY, new_buffer, new_buffer_size, new_buffer, new_buffer_size, &bytes_returned, nullptr)) {
    DWORD code = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "Failed to write to the drive. Error code: " << code << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(device);
    delete[] buffer;
    delete[] new_buffer;
    return 5;
}

std::cout << "Write successful." << std::endl;

CloseHandle(device);
delete[] buffer;
delete[] new_buffer;
```

But the IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_PROPERTY device io control operation fails with code 1. Why are the function parameters invalid?

Comment: Is `PhysicalDrive0` the same one with your OS on?

Comment: Yes, on PhysicalDrive0 is my OS

Comment: `IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_PROPERTY` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddstor/ni-ntddstor-ioctl_storage_set_property)) requires a [`STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddstor/ns-ntddstor-storage_property_set) structure as input (followed by the specific structure you want to set). You however pass a `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`. (It must be a `STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET` followed by a `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR` in your buffer). Most likely you'll also need to provide a valid output buffer.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: [Example: NVMe Identify query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/working-with-nvme-devices#example-nvme-identify-query).

Comment: No still not working, the code is in the post.

Comment: You're off by a few bytes - `STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET` contains a one byte array placeholder for the additional parameters. The second memcpy should be `memcpy(&((STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET*)new_buffer)->AdditionalParameters[0], buffer, buffer_size);` (refer to the example linked by IInspectable - that's why they use the FIELD_OFFSET macro in that example and cast the buffer to STORAGE_PROPERTY_SET - to correctly place the data in AdditionalParameters)

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it's still not working, the example also used NVME_MAX_LOG_SIZE, that is not declared, neither in the nvme.h. I put the code again in the post.

Comment: Now that i think about it it's probably unlikely that any device driver would actually implement `IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_PROPERTY` for `StorageDeviceProperty` given that most of the fields are readonly information. Why do you need to set `StorageDeviceProperty` / what fields are you interested in? / what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to modify the buffer that contains model name, etc., like not the `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR` itself and write that back to the drive.

Comment: @Turtlefight is right. Lots of storage properties are read-only. An error code of 1 (`ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`) is a common representation of the respective `NTSTATUS` codes translated to a Win32 [error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). Fixing the code that constructs the IOCTL parameters doesn't magically turn read-only data into read-write data.

Comment: As I said I want to modify the buffer that contains model name, etc., like not the STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR itself and write that back to the drive

Comment: I unfortunately think that that will be impossible. Basically all of that data either comes directly from the device itself (where it most likely resides in rom) or is metadata about that device (which bus it is attached to, if it supports command queuing, etc...). That data will be read straight from the device during discovery, so if you would want to modify it you would need to modify the firmware running on that device.